# Check for linear dependence in R3, given 4D vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have two vectors: $u = (1, -1, 0, 1)$ and $v = (-2, 2, 1, 1)$. My goal is to verify whether they are independent in R3.  I haven't been able to find a linear combination of the two that equals $0$, but I did notice that $u + \frac{1}{2}v = (0, 0, 1/2, 3/2)$.

My question is, does the above mean that the two are independent and form a basis of R3, or are they only independent in R2?

Comment: It is very easy to verify if two vectors are linear independent from one another. Is one vector a scalar multiple of the other? Check the third entries of both vectors and you can see...As far as dimension is concerned, both vectors are in R4.

Comment: Hmm, I did check for scalar multiples equating the two (see comment  regarding linear combination above).  My question is whether there it's possible for two 4D vectors to be independent R2, but not R3, based on the above.

Comment: I wouldn't even know what it means to consider a 4 dimensional vector in R2

Comment: Fair enough.  I think my textbook has a misprint based on this discussion.  It's asking me to verify independence in R3, but all the questions present 4D vectors.  Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frist, your vectors have $4$ coordinates so they don't belong to $\mathbb{R}^3$ so you cant' even talk them being independant in $\mathbb{R}^3$.
Next, they can't form a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ nor $\mathbb{R}^4$ as a basis of a vector space of dimension $n$ always has $n$ vectors, and the dimension of $\mathbb{R}^n$ seen as a real vector space is $n$.

Now go back to the definition of independant vectors in a vector space. 
$u$ and $v$ are not independant iff there exists a pair of reals $(a,b)\neq(0,0)$ such that $au+bv=0$. As none of the vectors is $0$ this amounts to the existence of a real $a$ such that $au=v$.

Suppose such a real $a$ exists, then one has $(a,-a,0,a)=au=v=(-2,2,1,1)$. 
The equality of vectors means the equality component-wise so we get $a=-2$ by the first component and $a=1$ by the 4th component, which is a contradiction.
Hence such a real does not exist and the two vectors are linearly independant in $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Comment: Fair enough. I think my textbook has a misprint based on this discussion. It's asking me to verify independence in R3, but all the questions present 4D vectors. Thanks for the feedback.